# I have trouble with order of dictionary's keys after init

Tags: ios, sorting, dictionary

i have storage of the entity "SchedulesItems". 
and when i try group result of this storage i have trouble with order of keys.
for example:

```
NSMutableArray  *keysForDictionary  =   [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray  *objectsForDictionary   =   [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSUInteger  index   =   0;

for ( EBResponseEventsSchedulesItem *schedulesItem in items ) {

    NSDate  *date   =   schedulesItem.date;

    if ( ![keysForDictionary containsObject:date] ) {
        [keysForDictionary addObject:date];
        [objectsForDictionary addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    index   =   [keysForDictionary indexOfObject:date];

    [[objectsForDictionary objectAtIndex:index] addObject:schedulesItem];

}

// in this line array 'keysForDictionary' have right order, just like:
// 25.09.2013
// 26.09.2013
// 27.09.2013
// 28.09.2013

NSDictionary    *returnDictionary   =   [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objectsForDictionary forKeys:keysForDictionary];

// but this line array [returnDictionary allKeys] have wrong order, just like:
// 25.09.2013
// 28.09.2013
// 27.09.2013
// 26.09.2013
// but objects which associated with this keys is ok
```

why sort order of the dictionary is broken?

p.s. sorry for my english - i am from russia

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not an array whose objects can be accessed by an index and thus have an order.
In a dictionary, objects with their keys are not stored in any specific order. The objects in a dictionary can only be accessed via their keys.

Comment: i know it. but i have not guessed try to use 'sortedArrayUsingSelector' for [returnDictionary allKeys]. thank you ))

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `allKeys` is not ordered. From the documentation:

> allKeys Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
>
> - (NSArray *)allKeys Return Value A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> Discussion The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

ps. It would be much faster if you combined these 2 lines:

```
index   =   [keysForDictionary indexOfObject:date];
[[objectsForDictionary objectAtIndex:index] addObject:schedulesItem];
```

into:

```
[[objectsForDictionary objectAtIndex:[keysForDictionary count]-1 addObject:schedulesItem];
```

Also, your logic will fail if date is not unique as IndexOfObject:date will return the wrong row in the array if there are duplicate dates.

pps. Why are you using arrays at all to build the return dictionary? Why not just add the elements directly to the return dictionary as you loop through the items array?

Comment: my logic will not fail because i want that several schedulesItems associated with 1 date

Answer (score 0):

As the others already said NSDictionary is unsorted by design.
You can however keep references to the dictionaries in NSArray or sort the keys afterwards like:

> NSArray *sortedKeys = [[returnDictionary allKeys]
>   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Comment: sorry but i have already try use this method - sortUsingSelector... it's not work ((

Comment: oh sorry - its working. i mean 'sortedArrayUsingSelector'. thank u so much!

Comment: You are right about the method name. I will edit my answer to reflect it.